# Can I get Google Analytics to ignore all sessions where the visitor only pressed the login button?

Tags: google-analytics

I have a site that gets most of it's traffic (like 90%) from users who are only looking for a login-button that will take them to a different site. This button is a customer requirement I'm not allowed to remove it.

This setup is currently an nightmare when it it comes to the statistics since we want them for all users who actually browses the site.

If I have understood everything correctly, this is the [solution](http://www.google.com/support/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481) proposed by Google (although _setVar has now been deprecated one should use setCustomVar instead):

> To exclude traffic from dynamic IP addresses, you can use a JavaScript function to set a cookie on your internal computers. You'll then be able to filter all visitors with this cookies from appearing on your Analytics reports.

But then we would exclude that user "forever" and that is not an option, the next time the user returns her or she might be browsing the site for information and should then be considered a regular user.

Instead of stating that the user always should be filtered out, I'm lacking some kind of session concept where I could invalidate the whole visit on a session level. E.g. if the user presses the login-button within say 5 seconds, he should be discarded from the statistics.

Is something like this possible to achieve or is there another way around the problem?

Comment: Why not expire the cookies quickly? Say, give them a timeout of an hour or so?

Comment: Yeah, that was my first thought as well. But I don't think it will work because the issue is really about invalidating the current page view that (I think) has already been tracked upon page load. When the user presses the login button, I can only set a cookie that will be used in future page views.

Comment: Have you tried a custom filter? just ignore clicks on the login button in general

Comment: Analytics does not track events like clicks by default so that is also impossible until I've implemented some kind of workaround. Google explains one way of doing it here: http://www.google.com/support/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55527 And still, I don't think a filter will be able to remove the first page view for me in the statistics. I can only filter out the actual button clicks, right?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're right, the profiles filter won't solve you're problem. You can only filter hits. In GA hits can be pageviews, events, etc. But if the user sees your frontpage and clicks the button later you already tracked that first pageview. There's no way to filter one hit based on future hits. Though you can filter out all future hits by using _setVar, and that's probably what you were told.

You're best bet here is probably to use a Custom Advanced Segment. These work on the session, opposed to the Filters that work on hits. If you segment a visit by page than the result is all visits that have visited that page. But if you try to segment a visit where page is not the virtual pageview fired at your buton click, than it won't work as one might think at firt. In fact your segmenting visits that have at least one pageview that is not the one you pointed.

The correct wat to do it is **create a goal to mark all visits that clicked the Login button**. And then **create a Custom Segment to get only visits that did not complete that goal**.

You will have to mark that button click, either with and Event or with a Pageview, so you can assign a Goal to it. The new Google Analytics Interface will let you create a Goal based on a Event.

Answer (score 0):

You can now do this without creating a goal. As long as you send an event when the users click the login button, you'll just need to create an advanced segment that excludes when Event Label = login.